# Scattered maps found in /proc/PID/maps

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel, elf

I was inspecting the memory maps of a Python process *on a Linux system* and found something very surprising. Normally, when I inspect the maps for a Python process they look like this:

```
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 fe:01 2904802                            python3.9
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 fe:01 2904802                            python3.9
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 fe:01 2904802                            python3.9
00637000-00abe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
...
7f67d8565000-7f67d8593000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f67d8593000-7f67d88ea000 r-xp 00000000 fe:01 2904547                    libpython3.9.so.1.0
7f67d88ea000-7f67d8ae9000 ---p 00357000 fe:01 2904547                    libpython3.9.so.1.0
7f67d8ae9000-7f67d8aef000 r--p 00356000 fe:01 2904547                    libpython3.9.so.1.0
7f67d8aef000-7f67d8b29000 rw-p 0035c000 fe:01 2904547                    libpython3.9.so.1.0
7f67d8b29000-7f67d8b4b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
...
7fff72a4f000-7fff72a70000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff72a7c000-7fff72a80000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7fff72a80000-7fff72a82000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

This has the following structure:

- All the maps associated with the same binary/shared object are contiguous.
- The maps for the executable (`python3.9`) appear first and the map for a shared library that is opened appear *after* the ones in the executable. This makes sense because the executable is loaded first and then the loader loads the shared object as is in the `DT_NEEDED` section.

But the maps that I found look like this:

```
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 67488961                           python3.9
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 67488961                           python3.9
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 fd:00 67488961                           python3.9
0067b000-00a58000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
...
7f7b46014000-7f7b46484000 r--p 0050b000 fd:00 1059871                    libpython3.9.so.1.0
7f7b46484000-7f7b46485000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f7b46485000-7f7b46cda000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f7b46cda000-7f7b46d16000 r--p 00a3d000 fd:00 1059871                    libpython3.9.so.1.0
7f7b46d16000-7f7b46d6f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f7b46d6f000-7f7b46d92000 r--p 00001000 fd:00 67488961                   python3.9
7f7b46d92000-7f7b46d93000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f7b46d93000-7f7b475d3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
...
7f7b5a35d000-7f7b5a827000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1059871                    libpython3.9.so.1.0
7f7b5a827000-7f7b5aa27000 ---p 004ca000 fd:00 1059871                    libpython3.9.so.1.0
7f7b5aa27000-7f7b5aa2c000 r--p 004ca000 fd:00 1059871                    libpython3.9.so.1.0
7f7b5aa2c000-7f7b5aa67000 rw-p 004cf000 fd:00 1059871                    libpython3.9.so.1.0
7f7b5aa67000-7f7b5aa8b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
...
7fff26f8e000-7fff27020000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff27102000-7fff27106000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7fff27106000-7fff27108000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  /vsyscall]
```

This has the following oddities:

- There is not a contiguous chunk of segments associated with the `python3.9` or the `libpython3.9.so.1.0` shared object. Indeed, there are scattered chunks for those.
- There are maps for the executable that can be found *after* the ones in the shared library:

```
7f7b46cda000-7f7b46d16000 r--p 00a3d000 fd:00 1059871                    libpython3.9.so.1.0
7f7b46d16000-7f7b46d6f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f7b46d6f000-7f7b46d92000 r--p 00001000 fd:00 67488961                   python3.9
7f7b46d92000-7f7b46d93000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
```

Do you know what can cause this effect or in what conditions this can happen? Do you know how is possible that a memory map for the executable is loaded *after* several shared objects?

Note: This is using kernel `Kernel 5.13.12-100.fc33.x86_64`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you know what can cause this effect or in what conditions this can happen?

An executable can trivially `mmap` (parts of) itself. This could be done to e.g. examine its own symbol table (necessary to print crash stack trace), or to extract some embedded resource.

> The maps for the executable (python3.9) appear first and the map for a shared library that is opened appear after the ones in the executable.

This is only true by accident, and only for non-PIE executables.

Non-PIE executables on `x86_64` are *traditionally* linked to load at address `0x400000`, and the shared libraries are normally loaded starting from below the main stack.

If you link a non-PIE executable to load at e.g. `0x7ff000000000`, then it will likely appear in the `/proc/$pid/maps` *after* shared libraries.

**Update:**

> the python binary here is certainly not mmapping itself, so that explanation doesn't apply

1. You can't *know* that -- you almost certainly haven't read *all* the code in Python 3.9 and *every* module which you load.
2. There is no need to *guess* where these `mmap`ed regions are coming from, you can just *look*.

To look, run your program under GDB and use `catch syscall mmap` followed by `where`. This will allow you to see where each and every mapping came from.

Comment: Yeah, bit this is not the case I posted. This binary *is* PIE and as you can see, the maps here are loaded at the beggining, is just that there  is a single map that appears after shared libraries. Also, the python binary here is certainly not mmapping itself, so that explanation doesn't apply unfortunately

Comment: @Dargor The `python3.9` binary in both of your `/proc/.../maps` is _definitely not_ a PIE binary, and as far as the binary not `mmap`ing itself, how do you know?

Comment: Because I compiled that binary and because I know what the program is executing.

Comment: @Dargor You almost certainly _don't_ know everything your program does. Answer updated.

Comment: Well, I certainly know what Python 3.9 binary does when you just start it because I am a CPython core developer and I have even written some of that code and regarding the loaded modules, there is none extra: just the interpreter at startup and the modules it loads by default, and I have indeed read those.

Comment: Using gdb to check where they come from is a good point, I will do some investigations regarding this.

Comment: @Dargor When you find out where the mappings are coming from, you'll also discover code which you haven't read. I suspect C++ exceptions may be in the picture somehow -- reading unwind tables or some such.

Comment: Seems that loading the process under gdb affects the layout of the memory maps :( I'm going to try to LD_PRELOAD some mmap hook to see if I can get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Meanwhile I am accepting your answer because if there is something going on is probably more complex than my initial question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Dargor GDB disables address randomization by default. Use `set disable-randomization off` to avoid that.